# Handling JSON parse errors of third party services in play applications

Tags: scala, playframework, ws-client

I'm wondering what's an acceptable approach to parsing JSON from third-party services considering deserialization errors.

For example, this service method:

```
  def signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String): Future[ApiResponse[SignInResponse]] =
    request("/signin").post(Json.obj("email" -> email, "password" -> password))
      .map(_.json.as[ApiResponse[SignInResponse]])
```

Will throw a server exception if `json.as` fails which play will catch in the default error handler.

Is that an OK structuring of the client? Seems like a JSON parse error is not really recoverable anyway, so uses the generic error handler is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ApiResponse` is going to hold any client errors (wrong password, etc) and the `Future` is going to hold server errors (couldn't establish connection, 500 from remote service, etc), then yes it's appropriate for the exception in the `Future` to bubble up to the error handler and return a 500 to your caller (also assuming there are no resources you need to clean up before returning).

Comment: thanks! yeah that's what I was thinking -- since it's not necessarily recoverable at that point. wish i could dive into some opinionated reading on this subject

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample to help you get started. This is a method that you normally write in your Play framework controller.

```
def dispatchPowerPlant(id: Int) = Action.async(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
    request.body.validate[DispatchCommand].fold(
      errors => {
        Future.successful{
          BadRequest(
            Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors))
          )
        }
      },
      dispatchCommand => {
        actorFor(id) flatMap {
          case None =>
            Future.successful {
              NotFound(s"HTTP 404 :: PowerPlant with ID $id not found")
            }
          case Some(actorRef) =>
            sendCommand(actorRef, id, dispatchCommand)
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

So what it does is to check the validity of the JSON payload and send the response accordingly! Hope this helps!

You could probably have a similar setup to validate the JSON and return the response accordingly.